# hit counter - technology is irrelevant - whats best to use?

Tags: statistics, counter, hitcounter

whats the best free hit counter? preferably one without ads. I dont mind what technology is used i.e php / java etc.

I also dont mind attempting my own if someone can point me in the right direction for one. Please dont suggest the log as I do need one displayed on the site.

Thanks for any tips - Bob.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind Google handling your tracking:

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: If you're using wordpress you can use this plugin: http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/05/share-your-google-analytics-data-with.html.